# MS Access Err. 3464, Typemismatch on Filter, How to set a Filter properly?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently working on a Database with MS Access.

The Problem:
I have a Main Form with a ComboBox (TNIDCombo) and a Subform. The subform contains a Table to be filtered, the ComboBox contains Values that are supposed to be used for filtering the subform.

Surfing Stackoverflow I learned, that you can bind macros on different states of a ComboBox, like "afterUpdate", and that is what I tried:

```
Private Sub TNIDCombo_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Proc_Error
If IsNull(Me.TNIDCombo) Then
   Me.DQ_ListeTNIDs.Form.Filter = ""
   Me.DQ_ListeTNIDs.Form.FilterOn = False
Else
  Me.DQ_ListeTNIDs.Form.Filter = "WMSTI_AUFTRNRAG=" & Me.TNIDCombo
  Me.DQ_ListeTNIDs.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
Proc_Exit:
   Exit Sub
Proc_Error:
   MsgBox "Fehler " & Err.Number & " Beim Setzen des Filters:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
   Resume Proc_Exit
End Sub
```

`DQ_ListeTNIDs` is the name of the Subform and `"WMSTI_AUFTRNRAG"` is the name of the columnheader of one of the columns in the subform that is supposed to be filtered.

Sadly, This throws the error 3464, type mismatch, when using the ComboBox in FormView
Can someone point the reason for that error out to me?

Thank you for any answers.
-Ninsa

Comment: Perhaps your _WMSTI_AUFTRNRAG_ expects a string? If so, you need quotes: `Me.DQ_ListeTNIDs.Form.Filter = "WMSTI_AUFTRNRAG='" & Me.TNIDCombo & "'"`.

Comment: I didnt even know that that could be a thing. The "WMSTI_AUFTRNRAG" contains numeric values, thats why I didnt think of that.
That Fixed my Problem! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gustav said:
`Me.DQ_ListeTNIDs.Form.Filter = "WMSTI_AUFTRNRAG='" & Me.TNIDCombo & "'"`
Did the trick. The Colum only contains numeric values, but the data type of the field is short text.. TIL.

Thank yu Gustav